# Heredoc commands for find . -exec sh {} +

Tags: loops, sh, heredoc

I'm trying to convert a hierarcy of TIFF image files into JPG, and out of boredom, I want to do `find` and `ffmpeg` in a single file.

So I set `find` to invoke `sh` with the `-s` flag, like thins:

```
#!/bin/sh
export IFS=""

find "$@" -iname 'PROC????.tif' -exec sh -s {} + << \EOF
for t ; do 
ffmpeg -y -v quiet -i $t -c:v mjpeg ${t%.*}.jpg
rm $t
done
EOF
```

However, there's just too many files in the directory hierarchy, and find chopped filename array into several small pieces, and `sh -s` was only succesfully invoked for the first argument chunk.

The question being: how could one feed such in-body command to every `sh` invocation in the `find` command?

**Update**

The tag "heredoc" on the question is intended for receiving answers that do not rely on external file or self-referencing through `$0`. It is also intended that no filename would go through string-array processing such as padding with NUL-terminator or newline, and can be directly passed as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heredoc is being used as the input to find.  I think your best bet is to not use a heredoc at all, but just use a string:

```
#!/bin/sh
find "$@" -iname 'PROC????.tif' -exec sh -c '
for t ; do 
ffmpeg -y -v quiet -i "$t" -c:v mjpeg "${t%.*}.jpg" &&
rm "$t"
done
' sh {} +
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did back in the office. Could you add a cherry topping by explaining why you believe I should use double quotes rather than setting IFS=""?

Comment: In general, I consider setting IFS to be fairly fragile and try to avoid it.  SInce it didn't seem essential to the question, I thought removing it would clarify the answer.  Adding the double quotes was more for demonstration of best practice than anything else.

Comment: In general, setting `IFS` to the empty string isn't sufficient, as unquoted parameter expansions are still subject to pathname expansion, not just word-splitting.

Answer (score 0):

I am re-writing your code below:-

```
#!/bin/bash

find "$1" -name "PROC????.tif" > /tmp/imagefile_list.txt
while read filepath
do
    path=${filepath%/*}
    imgfile=${filepath##*/}
    jpgFile=${imgfile%.*}.jpg
    cd "$path"
    ffmpeg -y -v quiet -i "$imgfile" -c:v mjpeg "$jpgFile"
    rm -rf $imgfile
done < /tmp/imagefile_list.txt
```

IF you don't want to change the current directory you can do it like below:-

```
#!/bin/bash

find "$1" -name "PROC????.tif" > /tmp/imagefile_list.txt
# If you list down all the .tif file use below command
# find "$1" -name "*.tif" > /tmp/imagefile_list.txt
while read filepath
do
    path=${filepath%/*}
    imgfile=${filepath##*/}
    jpgFile=$path${imgfile%.*}.jpg
    ffmpeg -y -v quiet -i "$filepath" -c:v mjpeg "$jpgFile"
    rm -rf $imgfile
done < /tmp/imagefile_list.txt

rm -rf /tmp/imagefile_list.txt
```

Comment: The program made the assumption that imagefile_list.txt wouldn't exist as something important in the current working directory.

Comment: Not really understood you. `imagefile_list.txt` this file could not be generated by your script?

Comment: Yes. I'm well-aware what sh does with the -c flag, the whole point of using -s with a heredoc is for better formatting. And saving the list to a txt file can and should have been replaced with a pipeline.

Comment: Also, path=${filepath%/*}, how can you be sure $filepath isn't a relative path? I didn't make that assumption in my code.

Comment: try to create in /tmp/imagefile_list.txt. Just check whether it is working for you or not. I am just trying to help you here. If not helpful I will delete my answer.

Comment: It's fine, this one is tricky enough that I had to give in to using -c before my boss set me a deadline.

Comment: What problem you are facing with my script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168227/discussion-between-dannyniu-and-abhijit-pritam).

Comment: Sorry my office network does not allow me for a chat

Comment: It relied on creating a file that may conflict with other applications; it relied on string processing for feeding the array of filenames; it unnecessarily changed working directory.

Comment: @DannyNiu, I have modified my answer, use the second option and let me know whether working or not.